# Getting a query param off of a dynamic page in next.js, possible?

Tags: next.js

I am finding IF a user enters my next.js site directly WITH query params on it. Mind you, the page itself is dynamic so it has internal "param". Using useRouter is NOT "seeing" the additional actual query param.....

So, I enter my site like so: Hard reload
-=> http://localhost/sku/1234?discount_id=TESTER

useRouter => query, only shows "1234" as being query{id: '1234'}. Nowhere IN the object of router is discount_id or its value?

This seems like a bug, no? I have to parse that myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The router.query param includes both dynamic route params and query params.

Try this code:

```
// File location: /pages/sku/[sku].tsx

import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Page = () => {
  const r = useRouter();

  console.log(r.query);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>sku: {r.query?.sku}</div>
      <div>discount_id: {r.query?.discount_id}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Open http://localhost:3000/sku/1234?discount_id=TESTER

Output:

[image]

Comment: ughh.. I refreshed the page, now its working.. LOLOLOL.. wtf.... I figured it wouuld do that...weird. Ok, thanks.